# jquery BA BBQ add animation

Tags: jquery, animation

I want to modify a little bit the [jquery BA BBQ](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/fragment-basic). I want to add some animations.

I try to replace the show() and hide() function with animation like this :

```
$( '.bbq-content' ).animate({ height: "100%" },1000);
```

But it does not work correctly.

I don't know where to replace the code in the original jQuery :

```
    $(function(){

    // Keep a mapping of url-to-container for caching purposes.
    var cache = {
    // If url is '' (no fragment), display this div's content.
    '': $('.bbq-default')
     };

     // Bind an event to window.onhashchange that, when the history state changes,
     // gets the url from the hash and displays either our cached content or fetches
     // new content to be displayed.
    $(window).bind( 'hashchange', function(e) {

    // Get the hash (fragment) as a string, with any leading # removed. Note that
    // in jQuery 1.4, you should use e.fragment instead of $.param.fragment().
    var url = $.param.fragment();

    // Remove .bbq-current class from any previously "current" link(s).
    $( 'a.bbq-current' ).removeClass( 'bbq-current' );

    // Hide any visible ajax content.
    $( '.bbq-content' ).children( ':visible' ).hide();

    // Add .bbq-current class to "current" nav link(s), only if url isn't empty.
    url && $( 'a[href="#' + url + '"]' ).addClass( 'bbq-current' );

    if ( cache[ url ] ) {
      // Since the element is already in the cache, it doesn't need to be
      // created, so instead of creating it again, let's just show it!
      cache[ url ].show();

    } else {
      // Show "loading" content while AJAX content loads.
      $( '.bbq-loading' ).show();

      // Create container for this url's content and store a reference to it in
      // the cache.
      cache[ url ] = $( '' )

        // Append the content container to the parent container.
        .appendTo( '.bbq-content' )

        // Load external content via AJAX. Note that in order to keep this
        // example streamlined, only the content in .infobox is shown. You'll
        // want to change this based on your needs.
        .load( url, function(){
          // Content loaded, hide "loading" content.
          $( '.bbq-loading' ).hide();
        });
    }
     })

     // Since the event is only triggered when the hash changes, we need to trigger
     // the event now, to handle the hash the page may have loaded with.
     $(window).trigger( 'hashchange' );

     });`
```

Sorry for English, I am french.